# counting items in a habtm association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't know what it is, but I can't seem to figure this out

What I'm stuck with is this, I have two models which have a HABTM association to each other.

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :events
end
```

So when I create an event, several users are associated with it. Lets say user 1 and 2 have 3 events that they are attending together. Now I want to count those instances. So I want to have the number 3 come back to me.

I guess it should be simple but I can't figure it out, can someone point me in the right direction? thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you want to count? Users or events? How does "Lets say user 1 and 2 have 3 events that they are attending together" relate to "So I want to have the number 3 come back"? Please explain more clearly what you want.

Comment: sorry I was not that clear. I tried to write down something that was not too complicated. Which I guess it wasn't. I wanted to count the events that (for instance) user 1 and user 2 were attending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know the quantity of common events for two users, then, without fancy SQL you can do it this way:

```
events1 = User.find(1).events.scoped
events2 = User.find(2).events.scoped

common_events_count = Event.where(id: events1).where(id: events2).count
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are look for all events that have 2 users in common, you can query all events and then filter the result down for each user.

```
user1 = User.find(1)
user2 = User.find(2)
events = Event.all
common_events = events.select {|e| e.users.include?(user1) and e.users.include?(user2)}
```

The variable `common_events` will contain the events that both user1 and user2 are attending.

Comment: thanks for the reply, both of your suggestions helped me a lot to get the result I wanted!